# Multiple Conditional Values for a Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with some sample values in a column:

```
 E00BC1
 171700
 8201C0
 C003A0
```

I want to add a new column and set the value of each row in that column based on the above data.  If the cell in the existing column starts with "E0" I want a value of "RA", if "17" a value of "SB", if "82" a value of "SA" and if the cell in the existing column starts with "C0" a value of "RB" in the new column.

I found this example:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G4,"E0")), "RA")
```

and I made it work once, for one cell but I did something to break it.  I also can't figure out how to nest the above to test for each of the 4 above conditions.  Excel keeps telling me that the formula has too many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CHOOSE with MATCH:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT(A1,2),{"E0","17","82","C0"},0),"RA","SB","SA","RB")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a little long, but one way to do it is with multiple `IF()` statements, using `LEFT([cell],2)`:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="E0","RA"&A1,IF(LEFT(A1,2)="17","SB"&A1,IF(LEFT(A1,2)="82","SA"&A1,IF(LEFT(A1,2)="C0","RB"&A1,""))))
```

Comment: thanks!  this worked and will be useful for some other things.